# Click CommandButton to display UserForm with URL link

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to code CommandButton1 to display UserForm1. In Userform1 I would like a hyperlink that uses values from cells in the worksheet. I would like UserForm1 to unload when the link is clicked.

I will put down what I (think) I know. But I am missing most of the code. Specifically:

How do I actually display the link?

How do I code to dismiss UserForm1 when link is clicked?

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm1_Click()
    Dim URL As Hyperlink
        URL = "http://www.example.com/" & Cells.Range("Q5") & "/index"
    ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put a label in your UserForm.

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim cellvalue As Variant

    cellvalue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Q5").Value
    URL = "http://www.example.com/" & cellvalue & "/index"

    On Error GoTo urlnotopen
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=URL, NewWindow:=True
    Unload UserForm
    Exit Sub
urlnotopen:
    MsgBox "Cannot open " & URL
End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks. As a follow up, would it be possible to code the command button to do this same thing in order to remove one step?

Comment: So if you have your commandbutton on your first sheet you can put the code 'Private Sub CommandButton_Click() UserForm1.Show End Sub' in your sheet. But you have to put a label in your UserForm and the code that i have written.

Comment: Did you understand what I meant?